# On update to 3.04 site started recording accents as "&Atilde;&iexcl;" and "Ã¡", what to do?

Tags: php, forms

One day my site worked perfectly and the next it suddenly started to have trouble recording accented characters. The problem affects posts' body, if I submit a post with an accent on the title it records it correctly.

However if I put it on the post's content instead of recording "casá" the posts "CasÃ¡" and if I edit it, it says "casÃ¡"

It's causing havok on my site because it's very "search based" and searches no longer work. I really don't know what to do. Anyone has experienced something like this before or has any idea of how to fix it? Or as a last resort is there a way to turn everything to us characters?

Comment: Can you check your `wp-config.php` and see whether `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` have a value?

Comment: I copied this from the WPconfig: define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
What would be the correct value? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Lisandro, 
in case you are still having these issues - or anyone else ends up on this page - the following.
Like Jan pointed out these issues have to do with the charsets.

In most cases the charset definition in wp-config.php must be UTF8, just like the variable for charset in wp admin read settings. Collation will normally not be set in wp-config.php, which leads to the default utf8_general_ci to be used.

Note that charset and collation are also set on several levels in your database.
As for plugins and themes: most important thing to check is whether a meta tag with charset definitions is added to the head of your pages.

In your cases you can consider to change the collation to utf8_unicode_ci for its better sorting performance. Best to have someone with working knowledge to do this.

Fairly good information on this can be found at http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Cheers,
Peter